# hidden/not displayed elements receiving mouse over events

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm pretty new to event-handling inside svgs and there is a little weirdness happening here. I'm doing an infovis where I build an interface and want to display different column-graphs. 
That's rather easy and working pretty nicely.
But I'm using hover-events to show the actual numbers when hovering a rect. it works with the one chart I'm generating first. But even though that chart is hidden (I tried both: visibility: hidden and display: none properties) the one that's drawn first still gets the event. 
Do I need to remove that one completely in order to generate a new one? So should I better work with separate SVGs and have an external interface, hiding the different svgs?
Any advice/best-practice would be welcome!
Thanks already!
Suse

Comment: show us the code so that we can see exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The other way of hiding things is to push them off the screen, as with hidden iframes. Just give them a negative x/y position. That should take care of mouse-over issues.